# Flask/Flask Restful - Get endpoint/resource method docstring

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

In flask restful, I have created an endpoint that lists all the others endpoints like many other have done as well. I can get the docstring of the resource class, but I cannot figure out how the get the docstring of the get/post/put/delete methods in the resource. I would for example want to document the available query parameters of a GET and the body of PUT/POST. This is what I've got:

```
class EndpointListResource(Resource):
    """
    List of endpoint descriptions
    """

    def get(self):
        """
        Generate Endpoints documentation
        :return: endpoint list
        """
        endpoints = []
        for rule in web_app.url_map.iter_rules():
            if rule.endpoint in ["static", "api.endpoints"]:
                continue

            options = {}
            for arg in rule.arguments:
                options[arg] = "[{0}]".format(arg)
            url = url_for(rule.endpoint, **options)

            methods = filter(lambda method: method not in ["OPTIONS", "HEAD"], rule.methods)
            method_descriptions = map(lambda method: {"method": method, "doc": "?"}, methods)
            endpoints.append({
                "endpoint": unquote(url),
                "doc": web_app.view_functions[rule.endpoint].__doc__,
                "methods": list(method_descriptions)
            })
        return endpoints
```

Comment: maybe help: [one](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/0.2/example.html#full-example) or [two](https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/0.2/documenting.html#documenting-with-the-api-route-decorator)

Comment: @DanilaGanchar: Sorry, but how to build a TodoList API and how to document an API using Swagger is not related to the question.

Comment: that's why I wrote 'maybe')) Could you add other `Resource`(for example `UserResource` with `docstrings` and expected output of `EndpointListResource.get()`?